# Twitter API Search: No media url in results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, twitter

I am doing the following Twitter API request:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23WOMGif
```

One of the results I get back is this:

```
{:metadata=>{:iso_language_code=>"es", :result_type=>"recent"},
 :created_at=>"Tue Oct 27 19:05:18 +0000 2015",
 :id=>659083467276361728,
 :id_str=>"659083467276361728",
 :text=>
  "cuando me dijieron que @womchile @WomChileCL va a tener 4g #WomGif https://t.co/x9nOwPosdP",
 :source=>
  "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
 :truncated=>false,
 :in_reply_to_status_id=>nil,
 :in_reply_to_status_id_str=>nil,
 :in_reply_to_user_id=>nil,
 :in_reply_to_user_id_str=>nil,
 :in_reply_to_screen_name=>nil,
 :user=>
  {:id=>119559070,
   :id_str=>"119559070",
   :name=>"Israel muñoz arevalo",
   :screen_name=>"blackisra",
   :location=>"",
   :description=>"diseñador 3d, infografo, musico, futbolero...",
   :url=>"http://t.co/DI7Kq8jr6W",
   :entities=>
    {:url=>
      {:urls=>
        [{:url=>"http://t.co/DI7Kq8jr6W",
          :expanded_url=>"http://israel.wide.cl",
          :display_url=>"israel.wide.cl",
          :indices=>[0, 22]}]},
     :description=>{:urls=>[]}},
   :protected=>false,
   :followers_count=>128,
   :friends_count=>181,
   :listed_count=>0,
   :created_at=>"Thu Mar 04 00:46:38 +0000 2010",
   :favourites_count=>91,
   :utc_offset=>-10800,
   :time_zone=>"Atlantic Time (Canada)",
   :geo_enabled=>true,
   :verified=>false,
   :statuses_count=>3598,
   :lang=>"en",
   :contributors_enabled=>false,
   :is_translator=>false,
   :is_translation_enabled=>false,
   :profile_background_color=>"131516",
   :profile_background_image_url=>
    "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif",
   :profile_background_image_url_https=>
    "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif",
   :profile_background_tile=>true,
   :profile_image_url=>
    "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/486269167490699264/qyA3H5gF_normal.jpeg",
   :profile_image_url_https=>
    "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/486269167490699264/qyA3H5gF_normal.jpeg",
   :profile_banner_url=>
    "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/119559070/1404771189",
   :profile_link_color=>"00BBCC",
   :profile_sidebar_border_color=>"000000",
   :profile_sidebar_fill_color=>"000000",
   :profile_text_color=>"FFFFFF",
   :profile_use_background_image=>true,
   :has_extended_profile=>false,
   :default_profile=>false,
   :default_profile_image=>false,
   :following=>false,
   :follow_request_sent=>false,
   :notifications=>false},
 :geo=>nil,
 :coordinates=>nil,
 :place=>nil,
 :contributors=>nil,
 :is_quote_status=>false,
 :retweet_count=>0,
 :favorite_count=>0,
 :entities=>
  {:hashtags=>[{:text=>"WomGif", :indices=>[59, 66]}],
   :symbols=>[],
   :user_mentions=>
    [{:screen_name=>"womchile",
      :name=>"WOM",
      :id=>3251660537,
      :id_str=>"3251660537",
      :indices=>[23, 32]},
     {:screen_name=>"WomChileCL",
      :name=>"Wom Chile",
      :id=>3367496379,
      :id_str=>"3367496379",
      :indices=>[33, 44]}],
   :urls=>
    [{:url=>"https://t.co/x9nOwPosdP",
      :expanded_url=>
       "http://twitter.com/blackisra/status/659083467276361728/photo/1",
      :display_url=>"pic.twitter.com/x9nOwPosdP",
      :indices=>[67, 90]}]},
 :favorited=>false,
 :retweeted=>false,
 :possibly_sensitive=>false,
 :lang=>"es"}
```

If I do a request specifically for this tweet:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=659083467276361728

I get the follow result back:

```
{:created_at=>"Tue Oct 27 19:05:18 +0000 2015",
 :id=>659083467276361728,
 :id_str=>"659083467276361728",
 :text=>
  "cuando me dijieron que @womchile @WomChileCL va a tener 4g #WomGif https://t.co/x9nOwPosdP",
 :source=>
  "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
 :truncated=>false,
 :in_reply_to_status_id=>nil,
 :in_reply_to_status_id_str=>nil,
 :in_reply_to_user_id=>nil,
 :in_reply_to_user_id_str=>nil,
 :in_reply_to_screen_name=>nil,
 :user=>
  {:id=>119559070,
   :id_str=>"119559070",
   :name=>"Israel muñoz arevalo",
   :screen_name=>"blackisra",
   :location=>"",
   :description=>"diseñador 3d, infografo, musico, futbolero...",
   :url=>"http://t.co/DI7Kq8jr6W",
   :entities=>
    {:url=>
      {:urls=>
        [{:url=>"http://t.co/DI7Kq8jr6W",
          :expanded_url=>"http://israel.wide.cl",
          :display_url=>"israel.wide.cl",
          :indices=>[0, 22]}]},
     :description=>{:urls=>[]}},
   :protected=>false,
   :followers_count=>128,
   :friends_count=>181,
   :listed_count=>0,
   :created_at=>"Thu Mar 04 00:46:38 +0000 2010",
   :favourites_count=>91,
   :utc_offset=>-10800,
   :time_zone=>"Atlantic Time (Canada)",
   :geo_enabled=>true,
   :verified=>false,
   :statuses_count=>3598,
   :lang=>"en",
   :contributors_enabled=>false,
   :is_translator=>false,
   :is_translation_enabled=>false,
   :profile_background_color=>"131516",
   :profile_background_image_url=>
    "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif",
   :profile_background_image_url_https=>
    "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif",
   :profile_background_tile=>true,
   :profile_image_url=>
    "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/486269167490699264/qyA3H5gF_normal.jpeg",
   :profile_image_url_https=>
    "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/486269167490699264/qyA3H5gF_normal.jpeg",
   :profile_banner_url=>
    "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/119559070/1404771189",
   :profile_link_color=>"00BBCC",
   :profile_sidebar_border_color=>"000000",
   :profile_sidebar_fill_color=>"000000",
   :profile_text_color=>"FFFFFF",
   :profile_use_background_image=>true,
   :has_extended_profile=>false,
   :default_profile=>false,
   :default_profile_image=>false,
   :following=>nil,
   :follow_request_sent=>nil,
   :notifications=>nil},
 :geo=>nil,
 :coordinates=>nil,
 :place=>nil,
 :contributors=>nil,
 :is_quote_status=>false,
 :retweet_count=>0,
 :favorite_count=>0,
 :entities=>
  {:hashtags=>[{:text=>"WomGif", :indices=>[59, 66]}],
   :symbols=>[],
   :user_mentions=>
    [{:screen_name=>"womchile",
      :name=>"WOM",
      :id=>3251660537,
      :id_str=>"3251660537",
      :indices=>[23, 32]},
     {:screen_name=>"WomChileCL",
      :name=>"Wom Chile",
      :id=>3367496379,
      :id_str=>"3367496379",
      :indices=>[33, 44]}],
   :urls=>[],
   :media=>
    [{:id=>659083465053360128,
      :id_str=>"659083465053360128",
      :indices=>[67, 90],
      :media_url=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CSWI62PW0AAoQnR.png",
      :media_url_https=>
       "https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CSWI62PW0AAoQnR.png",
      :url=>"https://t.co/x9nOwPosdP",
      :display_url=>"pic.twitter.com/x9nOwPosdP",
      :expanded_url=>
       "http://twitter.com/blackisra/status/659083467276361728/photo/1",
      :type=>"photo",
      :sizes=>
       {:medium=>{:w=>244, :h=>200, :resize=>"fit"},
        :thumb=>{:w=>150, :h=>150, :resize=>"crop"},
        :small=>{:w=>244, :h=>200, :resize=>"fit"},
        :large=>{:w=>244, :h=>200, :resize=>"fit"}}}]},
 :extended_entities=>
  {:media=>
    [{:id=>659083465053360128,
      :id_str=>"659083465053360128",
      :indices=>[67, 90],
      :media_url=>"http://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CSWI62PW0AAoQnR.png",
      :media_url_https=>
       "https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CSWI62PW0AAoQnR.png",
      :url=>"https://t.co/x9nOwPosdP",
      :display_url=>"pic.twitter.com/x9nOwPosdP",
      :expanded_url=>
       "http://twitter.com/blackisra/status/659083467276361728/photo/1",
      :type=>"animated_gif",
      :sizes=>
       {:medium=>{:w=>244, :h=>200, :resize=>"fit"},
        :thumb=>{:w=>150, :h=>150, :resize=>"crop"},
        :small=>{:w=>244, :h=>200, :resize=>"fit"},
        :large=>{:w=>244, :h=>200, :resize=>"fit"}},
      :video_info=>
       {:aspect_ratio=>[61, 50],
        :variants=>
         [{:bitrate=>0,
           :content_type=>"video/mp4",
           :url=>"https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/CSWI62PW0AAoQnR.mp4"}]}}]},
 :favorited=>false,
 :retweeted=>false,
 :possibly_sensitive=>false,
 :possibly_sensitive_appealable=>false,
 :lang=>"es"}
```

The second result includes the media_url, which is what I want (the link to the gif), however the first does not.

My only guess is that because the media is an animated gif it's not being returned in the search results.

Is there any way to search on the twitter api and return the media with all of the results?